# Python threads only executing once

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having in issue with python threading module. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
import socket, threading, ipaddress, re, time

from queue import Queue
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session, head, exceptions

self.q = Queue
for i in range(50):
    h = threading.Thread(target=self.myfunc)
    h.daemon = True
    h.start()
for h in range(3):
    for i in self.links:
        if not (i in self.prev):
            self.prev += i
            try:
                self.q.put(i)
    print(self.q._qsize())

    while not self.q.empty():
        time.sleep(1)
```

Sometimes this never finishes execution. I never get any errors. I have checked and the target function definitely always calls self.q.task_done even when an exception is caught. I tried adding;

```
print(self.q._qsize())
```

This showed that all threads complete one task each and then stop. So the queue is never emptied. If self.links is longer than the number of threads it never executes. How can I rectify this?

Thanks in advance

Edit: The function called is

```
def myfunc(self):
    url = self.q.get()
    try:
        r = Session().get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all('a')

        for i in links:
            item = i['href']
            if item not in self.links:
                self.links.append(item)

    except exceptions.MissingSchema
        pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    self.q.task_done()
```

Comment: I believe the issue is with `self.myfunc` only taking one item from the queue. Could you please edit your question and include it?

Comment: I think you need to call ```join()``` to wait for all the threads to finish.

Comment: That was my original code, however that just waited forever, with lists over 50, as well. @davejagoda

Comment: Is this python2 or python3? Can you show us your ```import```s?

Comment: I have found 2 problems so far: I think you want ```self.q = Queue()``` instead of ```self.q = Queue```. Also I think appending to the list ```links``` may cause some unexpected behavior since I believe all threads will be able to update it. Perhaps start from this example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join